# Failed to Resolve: Gotev Android UploadService

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In my current project I'm required to load a picture from either a camera or from the phone's memory and upload it to a server, reading online I found that the most common way is using Gotev's uploadservice, I add the repository to the dependencies in the build.graddle file:

```
compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice:3.2.3'
```

But when I try to sync the project I get the following error:

> Error:(32, 13) Failed to resolve: net.gotev:uploadservice:3.2.3

Complete Graddle.Build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.alejandrorodriguez.clientsapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.esri.arcgisruntime:arcgis-android:100.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice:3.2.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I highly appreciate help in fixing this error.

**** UPDATE ****

I tried Roy's answer and added the configurations.all however it's still not working.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.alejandrorodriguez.demoapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
            force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you just need to add this in the android section of your gradle file:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.+'
        force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'
    }
}
```

Note that 22.+ has to be replaced with the version used by your app, so if you use version 21, you will have to write 21.+